# send scope into onRegionTipShow

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jvectormap

I'm working on a Angular app, i want to use jvectorMap from Jquery into Angular.

I have found that angular can use JvectorMap so i did that code : [angular with jvectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/examples/world-gdp/)

I was attenting to reproduce [this comportement](http://jvectormap.com/examples/world-gdp/)

I can get the request and the data in the directive. I just don't know what i'm suppose to do to make the pop up work.

Comment: Share your code to look at

Comment: My bad i didn't link correctly but i have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.directive('map',
    function map () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EAC',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch("mapdata", function (n, o) {
                    $(element).empty();
                    $(element).width('auto');
                    $(element).height(600);
                    $(element).vectorMap({
                        map: 'world_mill_en',
                        series: {
                            regions: [{
                                values: scope.mapdata,
                                scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
                                normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
                            }]
                        },
                        onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code){
                            el.html(el.html()+' '+ upload.vectorMap('get', 'mapObject').series.regions[0].values[code] +' Photos');
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }
    );
```

the display:
[image: onregiontipshow]